# ArcPy Calculate Field management syntax error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator

I have list of GDBs each containing Mauza and Khasra Feature classes I want to update fields using string
code  is as below

```
import uuid
import arcpy as ap
import os
DistrictName='Faisalabad'#'SUBMISSION 11-05-2020/'
district='D:/ASADABBAS/Asad/DOA/Outsource/Recevied/'+DistrictName

def getGdbPaths(districtPath):
    gdbNotFound=[]
    directories=[os.path.join(districtPath, o) for o in os.listdir(districtPath) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(districtPath,o))]
    gdbs=[]
    for directory in directories:
        for villagepath in os.listdir(directory):
            if 'WITH EXCEL' in villagepath or 'WITHOUT EXCEL' in villagepath:
                for subvillagepath in os.listdir(directory+'/'+villagepath):
                    for gdb in os.listdir(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+subvillagepath):
                        if not gdb.endswith('.mxd'):
                            if (gdb.endswith('.gdb')):
                                gdbs.append(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+subvillagepath+'/'+gdb)
                            elif (gdb.lower()=='mouza'):
                                for subgdb in os.listdir(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+subvillagepath+'/'+gdb):
                                    if subgdb.endswith('.gdb'):
                                        gdbs.append(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+subvillagepath+'/'+gdb+'/'+subgdb)
                            else:
                                gdbNotFound.append(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+subvillagepath+'/'+gdb)
                                print('No GDB found in',directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+subvillagepath+'/'+gdb)
            else:
                try:
                    for gdb in os.listdir(directory+'/'+villagepath):
                        if not gdb.endswith('.mxd'):
                            if (gdb.endswith('.gdb')):
                                gdbs.append(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+gdb)
                            elif (gdb.lower()=='mouza'):
                                for subgdb in os.listdir(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+gdb):
                                    if subgdb.endswith('.gdb'):
                                        gdbs.append(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+gdb+'/'+subgdb)
                            else:
                                gdbNotFound.append(directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+gdb)
                                print('No GDB found in',directory+'/'+villagepath+'/'+gdb)
                except NotADirectoryError:
                    print('Invalid directory path',directory+'/'+villagepath)
    return gdbs,gdbNotFound
gdbs,noGDB=getGdbPaths(district)
for gdb in gdbs:
        ap.env.workspace = gdb
        mauzaid=(str(uuid.uuid4())).upper()
        expression='{'+mauzaid+'}'
        ap.CalculateField_management("Mauza",'ID',expression,"PYTHON3")
        ap.CalculateField_management("Khasra",'ID',expression,"PYTHON3")
```

when I run this code it gives me following error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Type of the field I am trying to update is GUID. How can I solve this issue?

PS: I am able to access feature classes but CalculateField_management does not seem to work.

Comment: gdb is the list of paths like "somepath/Spatial.gdb"

Comment: I have edited the code please check now

Comment: is it PYTHON_9.3" or PYTHON9_3?

Comment: `PYTHON_9.3` as per https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm#GUID-2E817E73-F1C8-42E3-9597-8BDEC11125E6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the error by using

```
ap.CalculateField_management("Mauza",'ID','"{}"'.format(expression),"PYTHON3")
ap.CalculateField_management("Khasra",'MouzaID','"{}"'.format(expression),"PYTHON3")
```

instead of

```
ap.CalculateField_management("Mauza",'ID',expression,"PYTHON3")
ap.CalculateField_management("Khasra",'ID',expression,"PYTHON3")
```

everything works fine now.

Comment: It should be `PYTHON_9.3` as per https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm#GUID-2E817E73-F1C8-42E3-9597-8BDEC11125E6